# Unable to use sendkeys for the selected html tag

Tags: selenium, xpath

Unable to use `sendKeys` for the selected html tag.  I am able to select the tag in Chrome console but not while executing selenium.

HTML i am trying to access

```
      <span class="_fp_t">
 <form autocomplete="off" action="javascript:void(0);" class="_fp_v">
 <input autoid="_fp_7" class="_fp_u textbox ms-font-weight-regular ms-border-color-neutralTertiary ms-font-color-neutralPrimary allowTextSelection hideClearButton placeholderText" role="combobox" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 25px;"> 
</form>
 </span>
```

I have tried by below code but it is not working

This is the html tag used in Chrome console:

```
$x("//input[@autoid='_fp_7'][@style='width: 25px;']")
```

This code used in selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@autoid='_fp_7'][@style='width: 25px;']")).sendKeys("testing10@yopmail.com");
```

Error thrown:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds

Comment: What error is being thrown?  Could you add the HTML of the input you're trying to access?

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is usually caused by the element being in a `frame` or `iframe`, or the element loading after Selenium attempts to perform operations on the page.

Comment: this is frame code used driver.switchTo().frame("<frame_ID>");